# preg match count matches

Tags: php, regex

I have a preg match statement, and it checks for matches, but I was wondering how you can count the matches. Any advice appreciated.

```
$message='[tag] [tag]';
preg_match('/\[tag]\b/i',$message);
```

for example a count of this message string should lead to 2 matches

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
$message='[tag] [tag]';
echo preg_match_all('/\\[tag\\](?>\\s|$)/i', $message, $matches);
```

gives `2`. Note you cannot use `\b` because the word boundary is before the `]`, not after.

See [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all).

Comment: Yeah you were right, I have to brush up on my regex skills. Thanks Art, appreciate the example.

Comment: `\b` *could* be used, it would just affect what is matched (i.e. the `[tag]` would need to be followed by a word character).

Answer (score 17):

[preg_match](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) already returns the number of times the pattern matched.

However, this will only be 0 or 1 as it stops after the first match. You can use [preg_match_all](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead as it will check the entire string and return the total number of matches.

Comment: Point for explaining the difference between the two functions.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) if you want to match all occurences. `preg_match_all` returns number of matches. `preg_match` returns only 0 or 1, because it matches only once.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). It returns the number of matches it finds. preg_match stops after the first one.

Comment: yeah thats what the other guys recommended. Thanks Manos.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com) with `count()` method (and even automatic delimiters):

```
$count = pattern('\[tag]\b', 'i')->match('[tag] [tag]')->count();

$count // 2
```