# PHP searching/formatting string dynmically

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have multiple different db strings, one for example is:

"Apples,Apples,Apples,Oranges,Apples,Oranges"

I want to represent each string dynamically as:

"I have Apples and Oranges. There are 6 in total."

Another string might be:

"Apples,Apples,Apples,Apples";

Should say:

"I have Apples. There are 4 in total."

How would I script this in PHP?  Ty for help!

Comment: Do you have any relevant code that you've tried? Or did you do any research and come up with any functions that you think may be a solution?

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064106/preg-match-count-matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $str = 'Apples,Apples,Apples,Oranges,Apples,Oranges';

  $arr = explode(',', $str);
  echo 'I have '.implode(' and ', array_unique($arr))
    .  '. There are '.count($arr).' in total.';
```

This should be self explanatory but for reference see: [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) & [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Answer (score 0):

I made this test:

```
<?php
$data = "Apples,Apples,Apples,Oranges,Apples,Oranges";

$array = explode(",",$data); //array of elements
$count = count($array); //How many elements

$arr_unique = array_unique($array); //array of unique elements

echo "I have ".implode(" and ", $arr_unique). ". There are ".$count." in total.";
//var_dump($arr_unique); //For test
?>
```

PS: Check the fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3u4-e5v