# cut text after html a ending tag

Tags: php

I have a comment system in my website and some users write very long comments, longer than 500 chars and I need to cut it after 200 and add the option "see more". The problem is that users can use `<a>test</a>` tags and in some cases the limit of 200 chars cuts the tag in the middle , like `<a>t` or `<a` or `<a>test</` If any of the cases above happens, the limit should extend until the end of the html tag so ex `<a>test</a>`

I have this code:

```
function truncate($string,$length=200,$append="&hellip;") {
  $string = trim($string);

  if(strlen($string) > $length) {
    $string = wordwrap($string, $length);
    $string = explode("\n", $string, 2);
    $string = $string[0] . $append;
  }

  return $string;
}
```

Any idea how to make this?

Thanks

Comment: Write a separate function tagCatcher(pass the entire text) 

In the function write out a quick check for a set of tags that can be used.  If you use a database to keep track of the tags you can just do a query.

Just a suggestion not an answer.  In your function you can count to 200 characters and then do some check for an '<' if it doesn't have a corresponding />' then extend until it find the '/>'

Comment: Suppose you could just write it within that function. I'm writing something up.

Comment: Do you know the above works?

Comment: i am not trying according to what you said, i gave your comment a vote cause i though you would do sth... 
i am trying to do it another way

Comment: this is a complex problem and not one easily answered with original code. Due to HTML not being a regular language we are limited in how we figure this out.  This is my thought process.  First we find all open and closed in the string with <([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1> then we keep that count. Then we use a similar regex to find how many open tags we have. Then we check to see if that matches the number of completed ed tags.  If we do not match at 1 to the count and do this until we have a match it's recursive so you can call the function within itself until you get an answer.

Comment: You can count the number of iterations and if that number gets above a certain threshold then cut it off before the last open tag

Comment: You can encounter this problem that way too as it is a bit of an exploit in your idea.  I could write a huge <span> and write all I want.  OR you could cut it off at any open tag that is left open after the cutoff and add that onto the show more.

Comment: Personally option 2 is better as far as exploits, and work the program has to do.  Basically you can solve your problem that way.  I'll try to write something up, but I'm at work so it's hard lol

Comment: <([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?) it to look for open tags only. so the function would take how many lines that is to right before that open tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think I did it. If anyone has any suggestion, feel free to modify this answer or comment.

```
function cut_text($string, $length = 350, $append = "&hellip;")
{

    $string = trim($string);
    $string_length = strlen($string);
    $original_string = $string;
    if ($string_length > $length) {
        $remaining_chars = $string_length - $length;
        if (strpos($string, '<') !== false && strpos($string, '>') !== false) {
            $string = wordwrap($string, $length);
            $string = explode("\n", $string, 2);
            $string = $string[0] . $append;
            $fillimi = substr_count($string, '<');
            $fundi = substr_count($string, '>');
            if ($fillimi == $fundi) {
                $string = $string;
            } else {
                $i = 1;
                while ($i <= $remaining_chars) {
                    $string = wordwrap($original_string, $length + $i);
                    $string = explode("\n", $string, 2);
                    $new_remaining_chars = $string_length - ($length + $i);
                    if ($new_remaining_chars > 0) {
                        $string = $string[0] . $append;
                    } else {
                        $string = $string[0];
                    }
                    $fillimi = substr_count($string, '<');
                    $fundi = substr_count($string, '>');
                    if ($fillimi == $fundi) {
                        $string = $string;
                        break;
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $string = trim($string);

            $string = wordwrap($string, $length);
            $string = explode("\n", $string, 2);
            $string = $string[0] . $append;

        }
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: my only problem with this is that it counts the number of < and > and not whether it is a tag or not.  Someone might use < in a comment.

Comment: yeah but still it is not a problem. i tested and it works perfectly.

Comment: This is the answer, but can be defined more to account for issues along the way. Good work.

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be this already somewhere on Internet but wasn't able to find it. What you basically need to do is count the opened tags and then if there are more opened tags than closed, it is open and can't cut yet. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3064151/1744702) is something to push you on right direction for how to easily count the number of tags opened and closed.

Comment: I feel thought this should of been a comment it was the solution in written word so I up voted this back to being zero.

Comment: @KirsKringle: thank you for that. I do agree in that I should've done more for this.